# Control the font and size of results of source blocks in latex export from org-mode document

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I was able to control the look of the source code in org-mode and export to latex with

```
#+attr_latex: :options framesep=2mm, baselinestretch=1.2, linenos, fontsize=\footnotesize, breaklines=true, bgcolor=bg, style=xcode
```

I was looking for something similar for the results section based on this [link](https://orgmode.org/manual/Results-of-Evaluation.html#Results-of-Evaluation). Without success, normally I work with Julia, R and Python, but all have the same behavior.

Any insight about?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the options for the package used to render your source code block. For example, since I am using package listings, I can set

```
#+attr_latex: :options basicstyle=\tiny\ttfamily
```

See [Source blocks in LaTeX exports](https://orgmode.org/manual/Source-blocks-in-LaTeX-export.html#Source-blocks-in-LaTeX-export).